# Wordpress - preserving office location in blog

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Here's a puzzler:  I'm doing a site for a client that starts with a landing page that links to  his four law offices, each with a color coded header and office info.  They all have content specific to their offices, no problem. But they also have some content that's universal, like a blog.  How do I put the blog in for all the offices but preserve the office info on those pages?  No, I do not want to use frames, but yes, that's the idea I'm talking about.

Comment: what you have tried yourselves?

Comment: I haven't tried anything yet Jothi, I'm looking for a strategy to make this happen.

Answer (score 0):

Couple different ways you could approach this, generally depending on how much information you need to share across the offices, whether you have requirements on how these different offices are administered, and generally how similar the content is.

The first decision to make is whether to use Single Site setup (in which they technically operate as one WP site), or a Multi-Site setup (in which you could use one common theme, but the posts/pages are administered independently  - you could still use a plugin like http://wordpress.org/plugins/network-latest-posts/ to share blog posts, but you'd want to make sure it meets your needs beforehand). More on this decision here: http://mashable.com/2012/07/26/beginner-guide-wordpress-multisite/, and setup here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network.

If you opted to go single-site, then one simple option may be to create page hierarchies, with the parent-level pages as Office A, Office B, Office C. If it's only a couple things that need to change based on the office (e.g. header colors, simple branding or info), then you could make a function that checks highest parent-level page (using get_post_ancestors - http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_ancestors), and use that result to determine which offices' branding you should use.

Best of luck!